# search form action url not display php variable

Tags: php

hi can anyone tell me whats problem in this form . its not show varible in url

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="post" action="test.php?q=<?php echo $searchb;?>" role="search" style="padding: 3.5px 90px;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="searchb" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

php code here

```
if (isset($_POST['searchb'])) {
   $searchb = $_POST['searchb'];
 }
```

when something input in form and action url not show any value

```
test.php?q=
```

but we echo variable its show value .

Comment: what is the output of `<?php echo $searchb;?>` ? url doesn't show any value because q is empty.and input value send as `POST`.if you want to see values in url then change post to `get`

Comment: just remove this `?q=<?php echo $searchb;?>` php block from the html form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time that form loaded `$_POST['searchb']` is empty so action is equal `test.php?q=` after load form when you submit form then `$_POST['searchb']` to be filled

Comment: how to change url test.php?q= to test?q= in htaccess

Answer (score 1):

> The Part: `action="test.php?q=<?php echo $searchb;?>"` is first illogical and most importantly unnecessary since you are `POST`ing your form. It would  have been valid if `$searchb` was pre-defined. However, since  it is a part of the Form; it will always be `NULL` since it was never declared but expected to  be dynamically added on Form-Submit, which wouldn't happen. You do it in one of the 2 ways:

**OPTION #1 - PASSING q VIA  HIDDEN INPUT:**

```
    <!-- YOU DON'T NEED THE echo $searchb PART  IN YOUR FORM'S ACTION BECAUSE -->
    <!-- THAT VALUE IS  NOT PART OF THE ACTION  AS IT IS NOT EVEN SET AT ALL -->
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="post" action="test.php" role="search" style="padding: 3.5px 90px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="searchb" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" />
            <!-- ADD THE q AS HIDDEN INPUT ELEMENT WITH A VALUE -->
            <input type="HIDDEN" name="q" value="Some value" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <?php
        // INSIDE OF test.php SCRIPT; DO;   
        if (isset($_POST['searchb'])) {
            $searchb = $_POST['searchb'];
        }
```

**OPTION #2: USING GET & SETTING Q TO A PRE-DEFINED  VALUE**

```
    <?php  $param = "some-predefined-value"; ?>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="GET" action="test.php?<?php echo $param;?>" role="search" style="padding: 3.5px 90px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="searchb" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <?php
        // INSIDE OF test.php SCRIPT; DO;   
        // BUT REMEMBER TO CHECK INSIDE THE `GET` GLOBAL
        if (isset($_GET['searchb'])) {
            $searchb = $_GET['searchb'];
        }
```

**BETTER OPTION FOR YOUR USE-CASE: USING GET & SETTING Q FROM THE INPUT**

```
    <!-- STILL NO  NEED FOR SETTING QUERY PARAMETERS MANUALLY-->
    <!-- THE GET METHOD WOULD TAKE  CARE OF THAT FOR YOU ONCE THE FORM IS SUBMITTED -->
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="GET" action="test.php" role="search" style="padding: 3.5px 90px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- NOTICE THAT THE NAME OF THE INPUT FIELD CHANGED TO; q HERE -->
            <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <?php
        // INSIDE OF test.php SCRIPT; DO;
        // BUT REMEMBER TO CHECK INSIDE THE `GET` GLOBAL
        if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
            $searchb = $_GET['q'];
        }
```

Comment: thank for reply but we need url link like test.php?q=somevalue when we any search value

Comment: @SaadAwan Check the updated post and in that case you could just simply change `POST` to `GET`.......

Comment: how to change url test.php?q= to test?q= in htaccess

Comment: @SaadAwan  You can't because the Query Parameters have  **EXACTLY THE SAME KEY-NAME (IN THIS CASE q)**. The latter would override the former. But you can do: `url test.php?q= to test?q2= in htaccess`  Notice the `q1` and `q2`...  Essentially, you just can't have 2 Query Parameters with the same exact name.... ;-)

Comment: i try this rule but not work `RewriteRule ^search?q=(.*)$ search.php?q=$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: @SaadAwan  It wouldn't because it doesn't change the fact that you have  **2 Variables with the same name**...